# Смена активных классов

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Столкнулся с проблемой , что при кликах на пункты , должен добавляться активный класс , то есть когда я кликаю на другой пункт , предыдущий становиться обычным текстом , а то что я выбрал к нему добавляется класс

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#sklad',
  data: {
    active: 0,  
  },
});
```

```css
.active {
   color: yellow;
   font-family: Montserrat-Bold, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
<div class="wraper">
      <div class="sklad" id="sklad">
            <div class="tabs1" @click:class="{ active: isActive }">
               <div id="sklad-one" class="tab active">Один</div>
               <div id="sklad-two" class="tab">Два</div>
               <div id="sklad-thri" class="tab">Три</div>
               <div id="sklad-forth" class="tab">Четыре</div>
               <div id="sklad-five" class="tab">Пять</div>
            </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Смог исправить , к каждому диву добавил такой элемент
@click="activate(1)" :class="{ active : active_el == 1 }"
@click="activate(2)" :class="{ active : active_el == 2 }"
@click="activate(..)" :class="{ active : active_el == .. }"

Vue
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#sklad',
  data: {
    active_el:0
  },
  methods:{
    activate:function(el){
        this.active_el = el;
    }
  }
});

Comment: Как сделать , чтобы первый элемент с самого начал был активным ?

Comment: И еще вопрос , хочу сделать , что при нажатии на слово один , выводится одна картинка , при нажатии на другое слово , другая картинка , я хочу , не знаю правильно ли так или нет , я хочу присвоить каждому  active_el класс , а в этих классах у меня хранятся картинки ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы можете сделать легко. Вы можете выводить пункты через **v-for** и создать функцию допустим **clickDiv** и передать ей **id** от пункта и в функции сравнивать **id** с текущим , если он совпадает то присваивать класс активный. Чтобы сделать 1ый элемент сразу активным можно указав id = 1.
Вот накидал пример, ссылка находится в комментариях

Comment: Не сильно понял как это реализовать , и насчет input тоже не понял , у меня же не его вообще в html

Comment: Извините я не правильно прочитал на счёт input. Что вам не ясно?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Вопрос насчет того , чтобы первый элемент был активным решен , как сделать так , чтобы при выборе пунктов , менялись картинки ?

Comment: Вот готовое решение: https://jsfiddle.net/andrew3273/36rozus1/ подставляйте в src нужные пути при совпадение id

Comment: Допустим добавить в 9 строк js такую строку  i[0] = 'img/eawe.svg' ? Сразу извиняюсь за такие глупые вопросы , я просто недавно начал изучать vue

Comment: В какую строку ? Можете показать код? Моя задача помогать начинающим , ничего страшного

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Young11/85a7v04c/4/ Я имел ввиду , что-то подобное , но он не работает

Comment: Во 1ых нужно было установить в jsfiddle vue . И вот решение ваше https://jsfiddle.net/andrew3273/0gp4nzd9/19/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Young11/85a7v04c/17/ Я добавил свой весь код , не знаю почему , но у меня при нажатии на список: Оружие , деньги , меняется цвет , но это не суть , вы написали 
id = 0
src: '...', а я могу как-то  вместо src добавить класс из css в котором у меня хранится картинка ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/andrew3273/shp69ucq/4/ так хотел?

Comment: Да , это то что надо , а можно как-то сделать , чтобы текст был через html , а не через vue ?

Comment: можно , но зачем? Через vue удобнее и легче потом редактировать список ваш. Если будет 50 элементов , вы будете в ручную добавлять лишний html и прописывать для каждого элемента с нуля

Comment: Просто мне нужно будет потом сделать так , допустим я нажал на кнопку взять , и у меня должно будет вывестись в игру название пункта , которое я выбрал

Comment: Ну это тоже легко. https://jsfiddle.net/andrew3273/shp69ucq/6/

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Хорошо, надеюсь помог вам